# Domain name automatically directing to HTTPS instead of HTTP i have no SSL cert

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

So i had a wordpress blog in wordpress.com. I mapped the domain name to it through godaddy.

The domain name was https://domain.com/ when it was active on wordpress.com however i moved my site to a self hosted site and adjusted the domain accordingly to point to fatcow subdirectory.

After mapping the site i noticed that in firefox i was able to see my self hosted website but in other browsers like chrome and IE i could not i would get the message below.

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from pogosmart.com
>   (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>   NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"

I also noticed that the site was going to Https not http, i have not purchased an SSL cert so i don't understand why i had access to https when i was hosted in wordpress.com... now that i am not, the domain still uses https.

How can i make my website http://domain.com/ instead of https://domain.com/ https is causing a "your connection is not private" error.

If this is not enough information let me know

Comment: Any reason you can't do the alternative and add a cert?  https://letsencrypt.org/ is free and open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to check two places.

One is the WordPress setting for the site's URL.  If you can log into the dashboard, you can find it under general settings.  Just take the 's' out of 'https' in the URL.

If you can't log into WordPress, you'll need direct access to the database, probably through phpMyAdmin.  Browse the wp_options table, and locate options named 'siteurl' and 'home' and change both to remove the same 's'.

Next, check for a file in the root of your WordPress site called .htaccess.  This may contain some code that redirects incoming traffic to the secure version of your URL.

Remove anything like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Your .htaccess should only contain something like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

... and maybe some extra stuff from any security plugins you may use.

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed the problem for me.